# Prove the orthogonal decomposition of a vector

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, orthogonality

Let $P$ be a $d \times d$ orthogonal projection matrix. Show that for all $\vec{x} \in \mathbb{R}^d$:

$\vec{x} = P\vec{x} + (\vec x - P \vec x)$

is a unique decomposition of $\vec x$ as the sum of two orthogonal vectors, with one in $\text{Ran}(P)$ and the other in $\text{Ran}(P)^{\perp}$

My attempt: Let $\vec{u} \in \text{Ran}(P)$ and $\vec{v} \in \text{Ran}(P)^{\perp}$. Then there exists an $\vec{x}$ such that $P\vec x = \vec u$. I need to show then that $\vec v$ must be equal to $\vec x - P \vec x$. Intuitively, this makes sense since $\vec v$ and $\vec u$ are orthogonal, so if $\vec x$ is a vector in the basis of $\vec v$ and $\vec u$, then $\vec x = \vec u + \vec v = P \vec x + \vec v \implies \vec v = \vec x - P \vec x$.

That's why I think the statement is true but i don't think I've stated it correctly.

Comment: Why would $\vec{v}$ equal $\vec{x}-P\vec{x}$? The quantities are completely unrelated in how they're defined, as $\vec{v}$ is just any vector in $\operatorname{Ran}(P)^\perp$

Comment: Isn't that the *definition* of an orthogonal projection? If not, what is your definition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$ and let $P$ be an $n\times n$ orthogonal projection matrix over $\mathbb{R}$. We show that there exist unique $v\in\operatorname{Ran}(P),w\in\operatorname{Ran}(P)^\perp$ such that

$$x=v+w.$$

Existence you've already shown, as we can take $v=Px$ and $w=x-Px$ (make sure to check for yourself that $w\in\operatorname{Ran}(P)^\perp$ here).

We now turn to uniqueness. Suppose $v_1,v_2\in\operatorname{Ran}(P)$ and $w_1,w_2\in\operatorname{Ran}(P)^\perp$ are such that

$$x=v_1+w_1=v_2+w_2.$$

Then

$$v_1-v_2=w_2-w_1.$$

But this quantity is then in both $\operatorname{Ran}(P)$ and $\operatorname{Ran}(P)^\perp$, which can only be true if it equals $0$ (if $u\in\operatorname{Ran}(P)\cap\operatorname{Ran}(P)^\perp$, then $\lVert u\rVert^2=\langle u,u\rangle=0$, which implies that $u=0$), and so $v_1=v_2$ and $w_1=w_2$, proving uniqueness.

**EDIT:**

The following proves that $w=x-Px\in\operatorname{Ran}(P)^\perp$.

Since $P$ is orthogonal we have the relation $\langle Px,y\rangle=\langle x,Py\rangle$ for $x,y\in\mathbb{R}^n$, and since $P$ is a projection, $P^2=P$. It follows that if $Py\in\operatorname{Ran}(P)$, then $$\langle w,Py\rangle=\langle x-Px,Py\rangle=\langle P(x-Px),y\rangle=\langle (P-P^2)x,y\rangle=\langle (P-P)x,y\rangle=0.$$ Thus $w\in\operatorname{Ran}(P)^\perp$.

Comment: I don't quite understand how to show that $w \in \text{Ran}(P)^{\perp}$. If this is true, then $\langle Px, x-Px \rangle = 0$. So we have $\langle Px, x \rangle - \langle Px, Px \rangle$, how can I show this is $0$?

Comment: @jemdo I've edited my post to include a proof that $w\in\operatorname{Ran}(P)^\perp$, hopefully that clears it up